# Can backbone view have multiple DOM elements as $el

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

My web application has an edit mode in which 2 panels slide it. One from top and one from left. Top panel with full width and 20% height and side panel with rest of the height and 20% width. I have created a backbone view for this. Usually I assign a template which is a single parent div and then reference it with $el.hide() and $el.show().

This case is different so my question is can a backbone view have 2 templates and somehow reference both together with id or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the direct answer to your question is NO. You can not have two `el`s associated with a view. However you can achieve this via a different design. You should have a master view and two child views (one for right slider and one for left slider). Now, Your edit button will be placed inside master view then you can easily show/hide the elements like this

```
this.$el.find('#right-slider').toggle();
```

Comment: `this.$ === this.$el.find` so you can use `this.$('#right-slider').toggle();`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk I agree.